# Use same file for both module and concentrated files in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm using `karma` for unit test, and `protractor` for e2e test with a mocked backend.

For these tests, there're some file for mocked response of web API. It looks like this in JavaScript, and it fits for both browser context (`karma`), and node.js context (protractor).

```
var mockResponse = {...};
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
    module.exports = mockResponse
}
```

However, I can't find a way to make it work in TypeScript.

This works for concentrated output (`--out`), in which `mockResponse` is a global variable.

```
let mockResponse: ResponseDto = {...};
```

And to make it work in CommonJS(`--module commonjs`), I need to write it in this way.

```
export let mockResponse: ResponseDto = {...};
```

My question is, is there any way to write this file, supporting both contexts? Thanks in advance.

---

I've found a solution. Thanks advice for @basarat, rather than using concentrated files, the test files are compiled to CommonJS modules, and using `karma-commonjs` plugin to load these modules.

Answer (score 0):

> This works for concentrated output (--out), in

Don't use that. There are lots of reasons : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/outFile.html

Instead use `commonjs` modules for both node and browser (with something like webpack).

## More

Browser quickstart : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html

Comment: Thanks for your advice, the principle helps.